# How to modify the default output of flask when it receives a request

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

Generally, when flask gets a requests, it prints something like this:
`127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2019 18:35:45] "GET /generateNodesDataTest HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

I don't want the entire path to be printed for each request. How can I modify that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The logging message you see comes from [Flask's default handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/#default-configuration).

But the default handler can be [configured](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/#basic-configuration) or even [removed](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/#removing-the-default-handler):

```
from flask.logging import default_handler
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
```

Comment: In the methods described using `dictConfig`, how do I modify the `message`?

Comment: in the `formatters` key of the dictionary passed to `dictConfig`